# Удалить текст от ХХХ до ХХХ

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Подскажите способ, как из текстового файла удалить куски текста помеченные маркерами `##start##` и `##end##`.
Слышал notepad++ понимает регулярные выражения, может кто знаком и подскажет как и что?

Comment: кстати ещё может кто подскажет как в notepade++ это всё сделать!

Answer (score 2):

Вот так удобнее:

```
##start##.*?##end##
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Откройте окно **Заменить**
2. Введите регулярное выражение `##start##.*?##end##` в поле **Найти**
3. Укажите **Режим поиска** - `Регуляр. выражен.` и `и новые строки`
4. Нажмите **Искать далее**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
##start##(.*)##end##
```

Comment: А что это регулярное выражение удалит из текста?  

    ##start##
        value 1
    ##end##
    other
    ##start##
        value2
    ##end##
И верно ли такое удаление?

Comment: что-то не получается(:

Comment: я так понимаю делать надо через "Заменить"
в найти пишу 

##start##(.*)##end##

а в "Заменить" ничего

но пишет: строка не найдена

Answer (score 0):

Может уже поздно, но у меня вот это сработало как надо:

```
##start##[^#]*##end##
```

Comment: Неверно. Вот в таком тексте вообще ничего не будет удалено.  

    ##start##
        value 1 #comment
    ##end##
Вот корректное выражение для нужного эффекта. 

     ##start##.*?##end##